# Is SVM a good choice for this imputing a numerical variable?

Tags: svm, algorithms, data-imputation, non-parametric

Let's say I have 10,000 training points, 100,000,000 points to impute, and 5-10 prediction variables/parameters, all numeric (for now). The target variable is numeric, skewed normal with outliers. I want to use SVM, but I'm new, so I would appreciate any opinions.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. The question is not clear, please give more detail. I'm not sure that you use the word "impute" with its usual meaning: imputing is replacing a missing value with some replacement value obtained from the other instances. Do you mean that you want to predict the variable as target?

Comment: Thank you! Maybe prediction is a better word, but we are indeed trying to fill in blanks in our data using values obtained from non-blanks, based on their orientation/proximity in parameter space. I am looking into techniques like kNN and SVM right now. I am, going to try this either way so I am just curious about people's opinions on this type of application.

What other detail should I have provided? I tried to describe the data without getting into the specifics.

Comment: Ok, from a ML point of view you're doing a regression task (as opposed to classification where the target is categorical). Usually SVM is used for classification but there's also the [corresponding method called SVR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine#Regression) for regression. Imho it's certainly one of the good options available, but of course it depends a lot on your data. Don't forget to keep some of the data where the target is know for evaluating the model.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you so much for your help with the terminology. Can you think of any other ML techniques that you would recommend for this application?

Comment: There are many options: linear or logistic regression, decision tree regression, k-NN... and I'm probably missing a few others.

Comment: Thank you. Those are the only ones I know of, plus random forest.